# How to assert validation errors of mongoose using supertest?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, supertest

I am trying to validate using `supertest` that the response returned by a REST endpoint contains the validation error of `moongose` validation which looks like below

```
errors: Object {
  firstName: Object {
    kind: 'required',
    message: 'Path `firstName` is required.',
    name: 'ValidatorError',
    path: 'firstName',
    properties: Object {
      message: 'Path `{PATH}` is required.',
      path: 'firstName',
      type: 'required'
    },
  }
```

I am writing following test

```
it('should return well formatted error response when first name is missing', function(done){
    var user = {lastName:"Ranger", email:"dan.ranger@gmail.com"};
    request(app)
    .post('/api/user')
    .send(user)
    .end(function(err, res){
        res.body.should.have.property("path", "firstName");
        done();
    });
});
```

But I am getting following error

```
AssertionError: expected Object {
errors: Object {
  firstName: Object {
    kind: 'required',
    message: 'Path `firstName` is required.',
    name: 'ValidatorError',
    path: 'firstName',
    properties: Object {
      message: 'Path `{PATH}` is required.',
      path: 'firstName',
      type: 'required'
    },
  }
},
message: 'User validation failed',
name: 'ValidationError',
} to have property path
  at Test.<anonymous> (test/userTests.js:23:25)
  at net.js:1276:10
```

How can I write such asserts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asserting that `res.body` has property `'path'`, however res.body is the parent object which only contains the properties `errors`, `message`, and `name`.

You could test for these properties, or you can access the nested error object as follows:

```
.end(function(err, res){
  res.body.errors.firstName.should.have.property("path")
  done();
});
```

It is likely more convenient just to test properties on the parent object, as this should prove sufficient.